# What is the quickest way to keep the non dominated elements and omit the rest in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

For example `[2 , 5]` dominates `[3 , 8]` cause (2 < 3) and (5 < 8)

but `[2 , 5]` does not dominates `[3 , 1]` cause though (2 < 3) but (5 > 1) so these two vectors are non dominated

now for example assume that I have a matrix like this :

```
a =[ 1 8;
    2 6;
    3 5;
    4 6];
```

here the first three are non dominated but the last one is dominated by (3,5), I need a code which can omit it and give me this output:

```
ans =

    [ 1 8;
    2 6;
    3 5]
```

note that there may be lots of non dominated elements in a Nx2 matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Compare one row with other rows using [bsxfun](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html)
2. Do this for every row using [arrayfun](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html) (or a loop if you prefer that) and transform the output back to a matrix with cell2mat
3. use [any](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/any.html) and [all](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/all.html) to check which rows are dominated
4. remove these rows

code:

```
a=[1 8;2 6;3 5;4 6];
dominated_idxs = any(cell2mat(arrayfun(@(ii) all(bsxfun(@(x,y) x>y,a,a(ii,:)),2),1:size(a,1),'uni',false)),2);

a(dominated_idxs,:) = [];
```

### edit

If you want to use `>=` instead of `>` comparison, each row will dominate itself and will be removed, so you'll end up with an empty matrix. Filter these false-positives out by adjusting the code as follows:

```
a=[1 8;2 6;3 5;4 6];
N = size(a,1);

compare_matrix = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(ii) all(bsxfun(@(x,y) x>=y,a,a(ii,:)),2),1:N,'uni',false));
compare_matrix(1:N+1:N^2)=false; % set diagonal to false
dominated_idxs = any(compare_matrix,2);

a(dominated_idxs ,:) = [];
```

Comment: thanks for your help.... what if i put ( <= ) instead of ( < )? for example [2 , 4] dominates [3 , 4]

Comment: test it out yourself, it should work. Actually you can put any function in the bsxfun call that makes a vector comparison of two rows and returns a logical vector of the same size.

Comment: i tried to modify it but it dosen't work the way i want ,,, i give [3, 4; 3, 5] and i want [3,5] to be remove but it won't

Comment: @MohamadPishdad: I see what's happening: each row dominates itself if you use <= as a criterium. If you want to avoid it, you'll have to filter that out manually. See my updated answer^^

Answer (score 2):

This problem is identical to identifying the so-called **Pareto front**.

If the number of elements *N* grows large and/or you need to carry out this sort of operation often (as I suspect you do), you might want to give a thought to a [fully optimized MEX file](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17251) for this purpose (available on the Mathworks File Exchange):

Compiling this, putting the mex in your Matlab path, and then using something like

```
a = a(paretofront(a));
```

will accomplish your task much quicker than any combination of Matlab-builtins is able to.